# I am admin, but I cannot edit system variables (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, environment-variables

-- Note, initially posted on Stack Overflow, comments suggested I post here --

Just upgraded to a new computer and am trying to install things that need access to the system path (e.g., arcpy, msys, and other things). I am the administrator, but somehow I don't have access to anything System-related. I don't remember having this issue on my old computer.

Screenshots below show (1) grayed-out system variables edit option; and (2) check that I am administrator (it also says I am in user accounts).

What am I missing to get full admin permissions? Note, I want to be able to add/edit system paths through the Environment Variables window, not through command line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you launching the Environment Variables control panel?

Comment: The edit button is grayed out of because you don’t have a variable selected

Comment: Did it work by the way?

Comment: @Smock, I did about half a dozen things at once, so I'm not quite sure what worked-- I also followed The_D0lph1n's answer [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/cant-edit-environment-variables-in-windows-10/29ca1561-5c4d-4c0d-ab93-808411a062a3]. Seems like these are all the different side of the same coin, but somehow it is now working. Thank you

Comment: It was also grayed out for me because I launched it using a shortcut that only opened "user variables"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### If accessing this through the *System* Page

`Windows + Pause/Break` will bring up the *System* Page

Then click *Advanced system settings*
[image]

This might get you to *auth* at this point - but even if it doesn't, it should ensure you're continuing as *administrator*

Click the *Environment Variables* button at the bottom
[image]

You should now be on the environment variables page as an Admin.

---

### If accessing through start menu:

*(Just noticed the other answer by Niall895 is pretty much the same as below)*

When you type '*environment*' into the start menu you will see two similar options:

#### `Edit the system environment variables.`

#### `Edit environment variables for your account.`

These may appear in a different order to the screenshots below, depending on which one you opened last. Make sure you select the shortcut with **system** in it:

#### `Edit the system environment variables.`

If you don't choose this option, the `system variables` buttons `New...`, `Edit...` and `Delete` will be greyed out as in your screenshot.

(It may or may not get you to re-type your credentials first)

[image]

---

It's possible you have different UAC settings on this instance

(Type UAC into start menu on each and look at the settings)

[image]

Although changing this just usually gets rid of the prompt pop-ups

Comment: I was indeed accessing the env vars via the Start menu ‍♂️. The other option, "Edit the *system* environment variables" will open a different menu -- just click **"Environment variables..."** at the bottom. (Thank you for pointing this out ⭐)